# Scrollable page with header fixed on the top using Material Design Lite

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I'm looking for a solution for scrolling over fixed header using Material Design Lite.

What I want to do is just like what Stack Overflow is doing. When you move your cursor over the header on Stack Overflow and scroll down using your mouse, the page gets scrolled down with the header fixed on the top. And the scroll bar doesn't stop on the bottom of the header. The scroll bar extends through the header onto the top of the page. This is what I want to do.

My web page uses the layout component from Material Design Lite. I use `mdl-layout--fixed-header` to fix my header. Even though the header is fixed and the page content is scrollable, I can't scroll the page using my mouse when the cursor is over the header, and the scroll bar stops on the bottom of the header.

How can I create a page layout just like Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add style: `position: fixed` to your header

Comment: I think your answer is correct. My header is now fixed on the top of the page and I can scroll the page over the header, but the header is now transparent and I can't click the links on the header. I thought it was because of `z-index`, so I increased the value of `z-index` of the header, and now it isn't transparent anymore but the header covers the scrollbar and I can't scroll the page over the header. Any idea?

Comment: Do you try to increase `z-index` of scroll bar?

Comment: Another option is moving your header next to `body` and all others element is inside one `div` which has the same level with header

Comment: I don't know how to increase the `z-index` of the scrollbar. Is that possible? If I move the position of my header, it will ruin the structure of the layout component of Material Design Lite. I don't think that's good.

Comment: Scrollbar of your website is yes, but scrollbar in the browser: no.

Comment: So, if the scrollbar doesn't work in browser, it's not good, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155587/discussion-between-imcvampire-and-tet).